# Moodle Additional HTML code not working well

Tags: moodle

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* FORMAT TIMER */
        $("#quiz-timer").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("position", "fixed");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("top", "50px");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("left", "0px");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("width", "100%");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("margin", "0 auto 0");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("color", "white");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("font-size", "150%");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("border", "none");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("text-align", "center");
        $("#quiz-timer").css("z-index", "1000");
    });
</script>
```

The above code is an additional HTML code which is supposed to display Moodle quiz timer at the bottom of the HEAD tag for every page during quiz attempt like in the image below.
[quiz timer display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm2gp.png)
Unfortunately the code works and displays as needed but on only a few computers connected to the Moodle server without working on a greater number of computers on the same network.
[quiz timer display2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OHdi.jpg)
I tried to purge all cache but still the same. In fact I don't know what to do again to make the code work on all computers on the network.
I would be very grateful if someone can help me out here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If all the script does is update the styles for all quiz timers, why not simply add a style tag in the additional HTML?

```
<style>
#page-mod-quiz-attempt #quiz-timer {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>
```

I always try to use the CSS approach when possible, although if there's a need for a more permanent fix I set it in the theme, or a local that I wrote to handle these quiz overrides, and leave the additional HTML for quick fixes.